# Find Unit tangent vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For the function $f(x,y)=4\mathrm{e}^x \sin(y)$, find a unit tangent vector to the level curve at the point $(2,2)$ that has a positive $x$-component. Present your answer with three decimal places of accuracy.

So I found the derivatives $(4\mathrm{e}^x \sin(y), 4\mathrm{e}^x \cos(y))$ and then plugged in the point $(2,2)$. I got $(1.031497356, 29.53821954)$. Then I divided $1.031497356/\sqrt{1.031497356^2 +  29.53821954^2}$ and got $0.0348994967$. And then I also did $29.53821954/\sqrt{1.031497356^2 +  29.53821954^2}$ and got $0.999390827$. When I put in $(0.0348994967,  0.999390827)$ it says it is incorrect. I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You computed the *gradient* of $f$ at $(2, 2)$, which gives you a *normal* vector. To get a *tangent* vector, you have to find one that is perpendicular to the gradient, and then renormalize it.

Comment: @Kovomaka I am not sure how to find the one that's perpendicular to the gradient, would you be able to give me some hints?

Comment: In the plane, the (two) unit vectors perpendicular to $(v, w)$ are $\pm(-w, v)$, pointing in opposite directions, and you can resolve this ambiguity using the additional information in the prompt.